# How to properly sub query - Or how is this wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch a load of database entries which include geo data that has to be fetched from another table. When i try to run a custom distance function on them it causes an error, I have tried to include it as a sub query but that does not seem to work either (The function does work).

```
$bsns = $this->db->select('businesses.name, businesses.about')
                            ->select('postcodes.postcode, postcodes.lat AS lat, postcodes.long AS long')
                            ->select('industries.name')
                            ->select('get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations('.$geo['lat'].', '.$geo['long'].', lat, long) AS distance', null, false)
                            ->from('businesses')
                            ->join('postcodes', 'postcodes.postcode = businesses.postcode', 'left')
                            ->join('industries', 'industries.IN_ID = businesses.industry', 'left')
                            ->order_by('distance', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
```

This is the code i'm using at the moment, The error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long, `industries`.`name`, get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations(50.344178' at line 1
```

New error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'businesses`) LEFT JOIN `postcodes` ON `postcodes`.`postcode` = `businesses`.`pos' at line 1

SELECT `businesses`.`name`, `businesses`.`about`, `postcodes`.`postcode`, `postcodes`.`lat`, `postcodes`.`long`, `industries`.`name`, get_distance(50.344178, `-4`.`757147`, `lat`, `long`)` AS distance FROM (`businesses`) LEFT JOIN `postcodes` ON `postcodes`.`postcode` = `businesses`.`postcode` LEFT JOIN `industries` ON `industries`.`IN_ID` = `businesses`.`industry` ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

Comment: `long` is a MySQL reserved word.  If you must use it, put it in backticks or change the name to a non-reserved word.

Comment: `long` is a reserved keyword http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - either name it something else, or wrap it in backticks `\``

Comment: @GordonLinoff Purely coincidental. Was typing mine as you were yours.

Comment: I would suggest to pay attention to your backticks and single quotes, this looks strange to me : get_distance(50.344178, `-4`.`757147`, `lat`, `long`)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing single quotes, the MySQL parser does not like it.
It thinks you're done with your statement.

```
select('get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations('.$geo['lat'].', '.$geo['long'].', lat, long) AS distance', null, false)
```

should be :

```
select('get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations('.$geo["lat"].', '.$geo["long"].', lat, long) AS distance', null, false)
```

Comment: Sorted out the first error, But now i get a new error - Edited into the post.